# Reducing the size of image results in losing some part of it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `CachedNetworkImage` widget in my code. Whenever i am calling it, the size of image is too large.
And when i tried to limit it's height to some les number, it's contents or some part of it are lost. I am unable to solve this problem. Here is screenshot of the image without any constraints -

[image]

I want only half of screen should be covered, while maintaining the width.And when i reduce it's height to 450, some part of it is gone, i mean it's lost(Check the photo, you will understand). Here's the picture with height 450 -

[image]

(I want only half of screen should be covered, while maintaining the width.)

(See, at top left corner of the main image in both pictures, and you will understand my problem).

Here's the code of the widget -

```
Widget cachedNetworkImage(mediaUrl, context) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    height: 380.0,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red,),
  );
}
```

Comment: Try removing `BoxFit.cover`

Comment: @Hamza no man, it still lose it's content

Comment: Try wrapping the `CachedNetworkImage` in a `Container` and then resize it, see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Boxfit.cover will ensure the image fills the 'area' you want your image in, without distortion. Because the image itself has a different aspect ratio than the area you have defined, then part of it gets cropped. Given your image aspect ratio does not match your 'containers' aspect ratio you really only have two options if you want the 'container' completely filled, the image has to be cropped or stretched (distorted) in some way. See this for a complete view of BoxFit: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html
The only other alternative is to ensure that your target container has the same aspect ratio as the image you want to put in it.

**Update**
The aspect ratio is just how wide the container is versus how high it is, like TV screens old and new 4x3 and 16x9. You can define a container who's size, or at least aspect ratio, matches the size of the image. You can then wrap it in FittedBox to have it fit the part of the  screen it is meant to occupy, on all device sizes. These layout widgets need quite a lot of trial and error before you get the hang of them. Just keep trying different options.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: can i change my Container's aspect ratio ??